# Why ammonium salts can not undergo substitution

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines, nucleophilic-substitution

Why is ammonium salt, such as RNH<sub>3</sub><sup>+</sup>, can not react with nucleophiles like HI to give RI and NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup>? The reaction is pretty much like the substitution of alcohol in acid condition.

In my opinion, NH<sub>3</sub> (rather than NH<sub>2</sub><sup>-</sup>) is a very good leaving group, so it can be substituted by good nucleophiles like I<sup>-</sup>. In order to prevent the resulting ammonia from attacking back, we can add more acids like HI to drive the equilibrium to the right direction.

I haven't found any signs of this reaction in textbooks, so I thought this reaction cannot happen. If it is a common reaction, where can I find more information? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: RNH3+ protonates any nucleophile that approaches it destroying the nucleophilicity.

Comment: @Waylander On the one hand, the scope of this reaction is indeed limited, but at least I-(Iodide) can act as a good nucleophile which cannot be protonated. On the other hand, If the ammonium salt is tertiary, such as R4N+,  the substitution is still possible, just as the cleavage of ether.

Comment: Quaternary ammonium salts are well etablished as good leaving groups but I can find no examples of a primary ammonium hydroiodide salt reacting to form a primary iodide as you suggest. Perhaps someone with database access can search this better than me.

Comment: @liwt31 Quaternary maybe?

Comment: @OscarLanzi yes, thank you for your correction.